# How to pass dynamic data inside model dialogue box in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Find below the code in blade file :

```
 @foreach($value['products']['product'] as $key)


    <tr role="row">
      <td  class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria- 
      controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria- 
      label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column ascending" aria- 
      sort="descending">{{$key['id']}}</td>
      <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" 
      rowspan="1" colspan="1"
       aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">


       <a href="" style="color:#23b7e5" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal">{{$key['groupname']}} - {{$key['name']}}</a>
       </td>
      <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" 
      rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort 
      column ascending">{{$key['regdate']}} - {{$key['nextduedate']}}</td>
      <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" 
      rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort 
      column ascending">{{$key['domain']}} </td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" 
       rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort 
       column ascending">{{$key['serverhostname']}}</td>
      <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" 
       rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort 
       column ascending">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">Auto Renew
      </label>
      </td>

     </tr>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog-lg">

     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><b>{{$key['groupname']}} - {{$key['name']}} 
      </b></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body modal-header">
      <p>Domain Name - {{$key['domain']}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a href="" class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item" >
            <span class="text-white font-thin h1 block text-center"></span>
            <p class="text-center text-muted customFont" >Email Accounts</p>

          </a>
        </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6"  style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="" 
       class="block panel padder-v bg-info item">
            <span class="text-white font-thin h1 block text-center"></span>
            <p class="text-muted text-center customFont">Addon Domain</p>

          </a>
        </div>
  </div>


    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a href="" class="block panel padder-v bg-info item" >
            <span class="text-white font-thin h1 block text-center"></span>
            <p class="text-center text-muted customFont" >Add Sub Domain</p>

          </a>
        </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6"  style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="" 
     class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item">
            <span class="text-white font-thin h1 block text-center"></span>
            <p class="text-muted text-center customFont">change Primary 
      Domain</p>

          </a>
        </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
         <!-- my modal closed -->
         @endforeach
```

In the blade file in the below mentioned code I'm getting the data displayed correctly but inside the modal dailogue I'm getting the same **name** for different **groupname**. Suggest me a solution to rectify this issue.

```
        <a href="" style="color:#23b7e5" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal">{{$key['groupname']}} - {{$key['name']}}</a>
```

For modal dailogue I have used the below code:

```
     <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><b>{{$key['groupname']}} - {{$key['name']}} 
      </b></h4>
      </div>
```

Find below the route code:

```
Route::get('clientlayout.main.myservices','MyServicesController@show');
```

Controller Code is given below:

```
class MyServicesController extends Controller
{

public function show(){
    $value = Whmcs::GetClientsProducts([]);

    return view('clientlayout.main.myservices',compact('value'));
}

}
```

Comment: What is the structure of $value['products']?

Comment: Any specific reason for placing `modal` inside `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on the presumption that there are multiple records in the table view and for each of the record, you want a modal to display its values.

I will not go with the data that you have provided, but the solution will work. I am going to take a single row off of a table.

**table.blade.php**

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
    <td>
        <a
            href="#"
            data-target="#yourModalId"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-id="{{ $product->id }}"
            data-name="{{ $product->name }}"
            data-price="{{ $product->price }}"
        >
            View Product Details
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
var productId;

$('#yourModalId').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var link           = $(e.relatedTarget),
        id = productId = link.data('id'),
        name           = link.data('name'),
        price          = link.data('price'),
        modal          = $(this);

    modal.find('.modal-title').html('Edit Product: ' + name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #price').val(price);
});
```

**yourModal.blade.php**

Now whenever a user clicks on `View Product Details` link, it will open a modal window with the dynamic values.

```
<div id="yourModalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title p-0 m-0"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body p-2">
                <form
                    method="POST"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    id="formEdit"
                >
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Product Name:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            id="name"
                            class="form-control form-control-sm"
                            required="required"
                        >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price">Product Price:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="price"
                            id="price"
                            class="form-control form-control-sm"
                            required="required"
                        >
                    </div>

                    <div class="errorsInEditing"></div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info submitButton btnEdit p-1 font-weight-bold">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this approach, you don't have to create multiple modal window inside the table view. Instead, create a single modal, and call it via jQuery inside the table via `a`.

Comment: Please try to refrain from boilerplate niceties when posting answers here - "happy coding" and "hope that helps" are items in particular that editors try to remove, since they're not exemplars of technical writing, and they don't add any meaning to the post.

Comment: @halfer.. Sure.. I promise I won't repeat that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

**Change date-target of link**

```
<a href="" style="color:#23b7e5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$key['id']}}">
```

**Change In model div id**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$key['id']}}" role="dialog">
```